# Android: How to get google map running?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have the following:

**Map Activity Class**

[image]

**Map Activity Class LAYOUT**

[image]

**Manifest configuration snippet**

[image]

*.. NOTE: I have also included the maps package under «application» tag.*

***In order to get API KEY I did the following:***

**Got hash from console**

[image]

**Obtained the API KEY**

[image]

**THE MAIN PROBLEM:**

***I see a grid instead of map images, like this***

[image]

**OTHER PROBLEMS / QUESTIONS:**

***How can I implement FragmentView (in order to be able to put some extra custom UI elements in layout) while having minSdk=8 and targetSdk=17 ? Can I use this tag on this range of devices?***

Comment: Did you see any kind of errors on Logcat ?

Comment: Could it be that your mobile network's just slow?

Comment: No critical errors in Logcat; I use the AVD which uses my broadband internet.

Comment: You need separate API keys for debug- and release-mode builds. Are you sure you are using the right one?

Comment: Well, i guess it is the debug one - which should be. I have posted all steps I took in order to get at this point. If some additional info is needed, I can provide.

Comment: You should use the MD5 fingerprint, not the SHA1

Comment: Ok, but where to get the KEY using MD5 ? I know a single place to get this - here: https://code.google.com/apis/console

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be if you place "android.permission.INTERNET" line inside the "application" area of the Manifest file. Try keeping it outside the application tag.

In case of failure

Try from the following examples carefully:

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-how-to-display-a-map-the-easy-way/

Answer (score 0):

So, Google Maps API v1 is soo deprecated that all Google Maps bussiness is done differently now (as said [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/)).

- Maps are now encapsulated in the MapFragment class insted of MapView.
- You extend Activity java class instead of MapActivity.
- Maps uses Google Play services APIs.

More than this (and the annoing part) - while reading [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start) I got [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html), where it says that "***you must provide a physical development device on which you can run and debug your app***".

That being said, you got to buy an Andorid driven device if you want to start learning/using/testing google maps and other stuff that uses Google Play services APIs. :)

If I am wrong, PLEASE correct me! I really hope I am wrong.